# Writing Labeling Expression for ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

How can I remove the alphabets and show the numbers only in a label expression of a layer?

For example, I have a field with values: TK209, 01TKRW394, 045TK, 089EYZ46 and I want to display labels as: 209, 01394, 045, 08946 respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the string by digits using [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method. Change `[Key]` to the name of your field:

```
def FindLabel ( [Key] ):
  return filter(str.isdigit, str([Key]))
```

[image]